# How to decode bitmap from cache file and from web

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am using this method to retrieve a bitmap

```
 private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
{
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from SD cache


    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        Log.e("URL", url);
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();

        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}
```

As you see above how do i decode the bitmap from SDcard or cache and from the get from web code? Ive tried one method but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for the file part take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html). Look specifically at decodeFile.

As for the Url Image take a look [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/converting-image-url-to-bitmap/) for a small tutorial on it.

Comment: public static Bitmap decodeFile (String pathName); this needs the PathName i only have the cachefile...